# Extract information from XML

Tags: python, xml

I'm using etree module. I'm trying to extract the information around `<text ...>` tag. Here is [my XML file](http://dpaste.com/637867/). I want if `<text ...">{{Infobox film` start with `Infobox film` then copy all the text between `{{ }}`. Is it possible? thanks

Update: XML file updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet should do what you want:

```
import re
from xml.etree import ElementTree                                               

with open('films.xml') as f:                                                    
    xml = ElementTree.parse(f)                                                  

for t in xml.findall('.//{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.5/}text'):
    print '===================='
    m = re.search(r'(?s).*?{{(Infobox film.*?)}}', t.text)
    if m:
        print m.group(1)
```

The regular expression there begins with `(?s)`, which turns on the `DOTALL` option, meaning that `.` matches newlines as well as any other character.  The two instances of `.*?` are non-greedy matches of any charcter - i.e. they will find the shortest stretch of zero or more characters until the rest of the expression can be matched.

Comment: Thanks But I want if `<text ...">' tag has `infobox film` values then print the text tag contents.

Comment: @user559744: I've updated my answer to show how to just extract the text from the `{{Infobox film ..}}` section.

Comment: Why I'm getting this message with result `print_movie.py:7: FutureWarning: This search is broken in 1.3 and earlier, and will be fixed in a future version.  If you rely on the current behaviour, change it to './/{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.5/}text'
`

Comment: I'd change it to what it suggests :)  I must have an earlier version of Python.  I've edited my answer to use `.//` instead of `//`

Comment: Sorry I'm bothering you. Is it possible also print `id`. With the help of `id`. We can determine this text belong to this `id`. thanks

Comment: I haven't checked this, but something like `r = t.getparent()` gives you the `revision` Element, which you can then run a `find` on to get the `id` Element.

Comment: I need your help again. Now I'm trying to extract first paragraph from same xml file. I have not found any luck. Would you please help me ? thanks

Comment: I think you should just ask a new question on this site, rather than adding more questions in the comments here.